# Adding Overlay arrow to endpoint doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm using this `makeSource` code and add endpoint styling according to the [docs](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/overlays#type-arrow):

```
jsPlumb.makeSource(connect, {
    parent: newEntity,
    anchor: 'Continuous',
    connector: 'Flowchart',
    paintStyle: {
        fillStyle: 'rgba(123, 123, 123, 1)',
        radius: 1,
    },
    overlays:[ 
        ['Arrow', {width: 10, length: 30, location: 1}],
    ],
});
```

I'm not getting errors.

[image: Overlay]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/C5ZLk/7/)**

For `jsPlumb.makeSource()` the attribute name is `connectorOverlays`(**[SOURCE](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/overlays)**). Here is sample code:

```
jsPlumb.makeSource("someDiv", {
...
endpoint:{
   connectorOverlays:[ 
     [ "Arrow", { width:10, length:30, location:1, id:"arrow" } ], 
     [ "Label", { label:"foo", id:"label" } ]
   ]
}
...
});
```

OR, You can set it in defaults as:

```
jsPlumb.Defaults.Overlays = [
            [ "Arrow", { 
                location:1,
                id:"arrow",
                length:14,
                foldback:0.8
            } ]
];
```

Comment: As you might have noticed in my other question the arrow didn't work. Would you be willing to extend your final fiddle with an example? http://jsfiddle.net/C5ZLk/6/ I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.